# Opencart - which language was used during checkout?

Tags: localization, opencart

I am getting translators involved to get my opencart shop into multiple languages and I want to pay them on commission for all orders made in their language (not country). At the moment I cannot tell which language a person has ordered in.

Anyone know a way to tell which language a customer was using during checkout.

Ideally this would be built into Opencart or an extension.

Comment: Why have I been down voted? I though this was a perfectly good question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that is saved in your database with the order itself (in the `order` table). You will see there is a field called `language_id` which relates to the relevant language in the `language` table. This is the only way to find this information out by default (though there may be mods that let you know this information on the extension store)